# Make double-clicking the middle button do something special

Tags: windows-10, mouse, button-remapping

I want to make double-clicking the middle button to behave as `ctrl+w` so that I can close a tab/window with it. How can I do that? I can't find any one trying the same.

My operating system is Windows 10.

Comment: Without knowing your operating system your question is impossible to answer.

Comment: @DavidPostill I edited. My operating system is Windows 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/), this will send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> if the middle mouse button is pressed in quick succession:

*ex. close_window.ahk*

```
~MButton::
    If(A_TimeSincePriorHotkey<400) and (A_PriorHotkey="~MButton")
        Send ^w
Return
```

---

AutoHotkey References

*[List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)*

*[Send](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm)*